# mongodb - many documents in one collection vs many collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb as database storage.

my web app has to collect user responses.

a user response is a document in mongodb (or a row in sql). length of a document is about 10~200.

user responses are categorized(to only one category). for each category, number of user response is between 100~5000. if two document is in same category, the have same length. (or they have same columns in sql)

a category can be dynamically created/deleted by request of admins.

currently, my data structue is

```
category collection
{_id, 'name' : 'c1', 'somevalue' : '123'}
{_id, 'name' : 'c2', 'somevalue' : '23'}
{_id, 'name' : 'c3', 'somevalue' : '143'}
{_id, 'name' : 'c4', 'somevalue' : '153'}
...

'c1' collection
{ userresponse1 }
{ userresponse2 }
{ userresponse3 }
...

'c2' collection
{ userresponse1 }
{ userresponse2 }
{ userresponse3 }
...

'c3' collection
{ userresponse1 }
{ userresponse2 }
{ userresponse3 }
...

'cN' collection
{ userresponse1 }
{ userresponse2 }
{ userresponse3 }
..
```

Is this a wise decision? I'm worried about possibility of something going bad by assigning a collection for each category. will there be some performance issues if I have many collections? should I merge my collections and give the userresponses some identifiers instead?

Comment: This has been answered a lot of times, normally MongoDB is good at scaling vertically. It is not as good scaling horiztonally up many collections. It cna scale many dbs but that might be overkill for this scenario

Comment: Whoops, when I said vertically I meant horizontally and when I said horizontally I meant vertically. Damn words

Comment: @sammaye Can you tell me clearly how it is? `growing vertically` means `few big collections` and `growing horizontally` mean `many (relatively) small collections`, and mongodb is good at having `many small collections`, right?

Comment: No horizontal scaling is having a few collections which scale horizontally across many shards (servers) in a cluster.

Comment: Though, reading your question again, as to whether this is bad or not depends on how many categories you intend to have. I mean you can't be having that many categories right? The default namespace allows around 12k collections plus a small amount of indexes per collection. However having that amount of indexes on a primary could create performance problems over the ability to shard your index across multiple servers saving you a lot of hassle in the long run.

Comment: To explain my last comment a bit better, imagine you have 9 categories. In a normal singularly horizontal scaled collection you will only house 1/9th of that data on the master but using many collections can mean that actually you are dumping all that data onto your master. This might exceed Virtual Memory and cause page thrashing of your OS' LRU. But this is all theory here and it comes down to specifics like your actual schema and servers etc.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the answer depends on you query patterns and how many collections you're looking at having. Without knowing more, I would suspect that you would need to make queries that span many of the response collections.

For example if each `userresponse` had a `userId` field and suppose you wanted to get a date sorted list of all the responses for a specific user.  You would need to loop over all the collections, query each, and combine the results in client code.  Obviously this would be highly inefficient compared to a single simple query/sort in an indexed `UserResponse` collection.

Comment: Apart from your access pattern you also need to consider how MongoDB handles storage and especially deletion of documents. The space being free'd when deleting a document isn't automatically made available for other collections, but only for the collection it was deleted from.