# MongoDB: Perform same operation across multiple collections

Tags: mongodb

I have taken a large collection that I split up into many collections using the [split collection philosophy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607443/mongodb-many-documents-in-one-collection-vs-many-collection). Say I want to remove a field from all collections. Usually I would use pymongo API and do something like:

```
for collections in connection.collection_names():
     connection[collection].update({},{"$unset":{"myfield":1}},multi=True)
```

Is there a way to do this within the mongo shell?

Wish there was something like:

```
use mydatabase
mydatabase.*.update({},{$unset:{"myfield":1}},{multi:true})
```

Or something like

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(func(obj)){db.obj.update()
```

But I can't figure out how to iterate through the collection names in the shell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet to do that:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection){
    db[collection].update({},{$unset:{"myfield":1}},{multi:true});
});
```

Hope this helps :)